# Cannot access magento admin panel after clone from git repository

Tags: php, git, magento

I just did the following steps:

1. download all folders&files from Magento root
2. add these folders&files to git repository
3. delete Magento root, git clone

Everything works fine include Magento connect, but when I try to access the admin panel, it just shows me a blank white page with 500 internal error.

But as there is nothing in `var/log` and `var/report`, how can I find out what's the problem?

*I've already changed the permission and created the empty folder.

*I'm using Magento 1.9.2.4.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I've tried to fix it in last two days, but after post this question I found the reason accidentally.

It's a shame that I don't know why there're two adminhtml folders under design folder as following.

1. app/design/adminhtml
2. app/design/Adminhtml

After I downloaded the project from server to my windows(That is the key point). It automatically left the capital one and deleted the correct adminhtml folder. Of course there was only app/design/Adminhtml in my git repository so error occurred.